# Can I use compound sentences and relative clauses in complex sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

Can I use compound sentences and relative clauses in complex sentence?

> Although Mr. McConnell waited until weeks after Mr. Biden was declared the winner to recognize the outcome, his actions were a clear bid by the majority leader, who is the most powerful Republican in Congress, to put an end to his party’s attempts to sow doubt about the election. ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/15/us/politics/mcconnell-congratulates-biden.html))

Comment: I don't know if you can, but it's definitely hard to parse.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please remember to include your source in the question. I have done that for you this time. For future reference, please always tell us where you found your sentence. Also, I am not quite clear on what you are asking here. What exactly are you having trouble with in this passage?

Comment: Could I write transition sentence in first dependent clauses or  subordinating clauses? "after Mr.Biden was 
 Declared the winner to recognise this outcome" Could I write relative clauses  like" who is the most powerful Republican in Congress"?